# Calling .load() repeatedly without causing duplicate scripts

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, duplicates, infinite-scroll

I have been struggling with this and searching through similar answers on SO, but can't seem to figure this out.

I have an activity feed that I am loading from an external PHP file using .load(). The external file contains scripts to count characters in textarea and truncate long posts such as:

```
$('.watermark_comment').jqEasyCounter({'maxChars': 2000,'maxCharsWarning': 1990,'msgFontSize': '10px','msgFontColor': '#666666','msgFontFamily': 'Arial','msgTextAlign': 'left','msgWarningColor': '#F00','msgAppendMethod': 'insertAfter' });  $('.truncate').jTruncate();
```

Everything works perfectly when the page first loads. However, I also have a script in the external file to create endless scrolling. The 'href' contains the paging querystring:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 500) {
    //Add something at the end of the page
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('#activity_feed_load').load($('.older_posts:last').attr('href'));
    $('.older_posts:first').remove();
    }
    });
```

The problem is that as soon as the scroll function is called and the .load is called again the scripts applied to any selectors previously in the feed get 'doubled up'. For example, each time the .load() is called there becomes two countdowns corresponding to the jqEasyCounter and two 'more' corresponding to the jTruncate. Each time .load is called the number of instances is incremented by one.

I've read other posts discussing how to properly load files using a selector to remove the scripts and then using getscripts. But how would I do this when I am calling .load repeatedly and appending the results?

Would really appreciate some help on this!

**Update**
Ok, based on Kevin's suggestions, I have removed the load script from the external file and placed it in the main file as follows:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
     if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 500) {
    //Add something at the end of the page
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('#activity_feed_load #no_script').load($('.older_posts').not(".ignore").attr('href')).done(function(){
    $('.older_posts').not(".ignore").addClass("ignore");
    $('.watermark_comment').not(".initialized").jqEasyCounter({
         'maxChars': 2000,
        'maxCharsWarning': 1990,
        'msgFontSize': '10px',
        'msgFontColor': '#666666',
        'msgFontFamily': 'Arial',
        'msgTextAlign': 'left',
        'msgWarningColor': '#F00',
        'msgAppendMethod': 'insertAfter'              
        }).addClass("initialized");

    });
    }
    });
```

I'm trying to remove the pager link after the load and then use the latest pager link the next time the load is called. Unfortunately, the script fires once when I scroll and then the page freezes. Not sure if I'm binding the scroll event correctly. Should I be using .on() or .live() instead?

Comment: do you have any chance to change the content of the loaded feed? otherwise i would strip the script tag from the loaded data before inserting it into the dom

Comment: I would provide a selector to `.load` that targets the content that needs to be appended. `.load(theHref + " #someId")`

Comment: @gpasci thanks for the response. I'm not sure I understand your question. Yes, I can alter the content and structure of the external file. If I take out the scripts from the loaded data, how do I apply them again in the page? That's the part that I'm stuck on. Thanks!

Comment: @kevin Yes, I've tried targeting a div in the external file, but then I don't have the functionality of the scripts. Any idea how to add this for each load event so that it doesn't cause duplicates in previously loaded items? Thanks!

Comment: Can you bind that functionality using event delegation?

Comment: That's a good suggestion @KevinB . The scripts that bind using event delegation such as deleting a post or comment seem to be working fine. However, I'm not sure how I would do that with the character counter and truncate plugins I'm using. Right now, they are simply applied to the selectors. Do you know of a way I could do that?

Comment: Sorry, I take that back. Even the scripts that are binded to click events are getting 'doubled up'. For example, I'm able to delete a post, but the script will run as many times as .load has been called.

Comment: I usually have all ui event handlers initialized on dom ready, or on window load, waiting for user interaction on particular divs (css selectors in general). handlers are attached to parent divs loaded before the actual content. this way you can load content only, having event logic already defined and waiting an interaction on the parent/container div...I know my english is quite bad, I can provide some examples to be more clear

Comment: @gpasci thanks for the suggestions. Glad I got it working finally!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading only a specific piece of the external file using:

```
.load(theHref + " #someId");
```

Next, use event delegation to bind events,

```
$(document).delegate("event","selector",event);
```

Finally, use the done callback to initialize any plugins.

```
$("#target").load(theHref + " #someId").done(function(){
    $(".someEl", "#target").not(".initialized").myPlugin().addClass("initialized");
})
```

Comment: So the event delegation script should go in the main page that is calling the external file and I should remove all scripts from the external file?

Comment: If I initialize the plugins in the .load callback, what prevents them from still being loaded multiple times with each .load?

Comment: Target only the ones inside of the div you are loading content into. Since that div gets emptied, it will always be hitting un-initialized elements.

Comment: I think the issue is that I'm appending the loaded content. It's not completely replacing the content of the target. So elements are already existing on the page when more elements are appended to the div.

Comment: In that case, use a class to differentiate between the ones that have already been initialized and the ones that haven't. updating.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work exactly as you recommended, but I was able to simply leave the scripts in the external file and load the entire file. I then added and checked for the "initialized" class to eliminate the duplicates. Thanks for the help!